# why are we actually using helper text in textField MUI on yup validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

```
<TextField
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.password}
              name="password"
              error={Boolean(touched.password) && Boolean(errors.password)}
              helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
/>
```

I had no issues and it works fine but why is it necessary to add helper text in the above

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

For accessibility and to improve user experience, the helper text give the user a more understanding of what he is doing wrong and why the form field is invalid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).